# directory index of <directory> is forbiden

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a dashboard that leads to different applications depending on the routes. I'm running Nginx inside a docker container and the way I structured the folders is the following starting on /usr/share/nginx/html:

```
usr/share/nginx/html
  index.html
  app1
    index.html
  app2
    index.html
  ...
  appN
    index.html
```

And my nginx.conf looks something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  server_name server;

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;


  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass <pass>;
  }

  location /app1/ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/app1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /app1/api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass <proxy>;
  }

  location /app2/ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/app2;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /app2/api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass <proxy>;
  }
}
```

Whenever I go to the root everything works and I see the HTML file. But when I try to access any of the routes I keep receiving the message "directory index of usr/share/nginx/html/appN is forbiden". I already tried removing try_files and adding `index index.htm index.html` but I can not make it work.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: All of your `alias` statements appear to be unnecessary, you should remove them all.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. I noticed all the trial and error was not working because I didn't redirect the static files generated by the react build. (PUBLIC_URL)